# covariance of order statistic

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, proof, order-statistics

Could you help me to proof that $COV(\bar{X},X_{(1)})$ = $Var(X_{(1)})$?  Here, let $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ be random sample from two-parameter exponential distribution with parameters $(\lambda,\theta)$. The pdf. is $f(x)= \frac{1}{\lambda} \exp{(-(x-\theta)/\lambda)}$. I know that $X_{(1)}$ follows two-parameter exponential distribution with parameters $(\lambda/n,\theta)$.

And why $\sum_{i=1}^n COV(X_{i},X_{(1)})=C_{n,1}COV(X_{(1)},X_{(1)})$?

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
Use $\mathrm{Cov}(X+Y,Z) = \mathrm{Cov}(X,Z)+\mathrm{Cov}(Y,Z)$ and $\mathrm{Cov}(cX,Z) = c\mathrm{Cov}(X,Z)$ for constanct $c$

$\mathrm{Cov}(\bar{X},X_{(1)}) = \frac{1}{n}\mathrm{Var}(X_{(1)})+\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{Cov}(X_{(1)}, X_{(2)})+ \dots$